# how to replace array of object with an object in javascript without repeating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let a = [{ name: "ben", age: 25 }, { name: "jeffrey", age: 10 },{ name: "daniel", age: 20 }]
let case1 = { name: "ben", age: 10 }
let case2={ name: "jack", age: 30 }
```

case1:
i expect the result to be

```
[{ name: "ben", age: 10 }, { name: "jeffrey", age: 10 },{ name: "daniel", age: 20 }]
```

where "ben" is existing so it replaces age to 10

case2:
i expect the result to be

```
[{ name: "ben", age: 25 }, { name: "jeffrey", age: 10 },{ name: "daniel", age: 20 },{ name: "jack", age: 30 }]
```

where "jack" is not there in the array so it adds to the array

how to write a function which does this functionality

Comment: Every method to solve this problem that makes any kind of sense will use some form of iteration (repeating).

Comment: @Kevin B  - Iteration yes it's necessary but this could be done by JS itself through using `find`or `findIndex`.

Comment: @Sascha which... iterates over the array.

Comment: @Kevin B -Yes, but where is the problem to itereate over the array?

Comment: @Sascha No, of course not, however the asker specifically asked not to. My comment was for the asker.

Comment: @Kevin B - `without repeating` means for me without a loop (for, foreach, wile, ... and perhaps without map, reduce, ... with there callbacks) but not without standard functionality of JS.

Comment: @Sascha I disagree, but, again, i'm in no way saying answers shouldn't use repeating... quite the opposite in fact.

Comment: @BenFranklin You should clarify what you meant in your title by 'without repeating'

Comment: Either you have hash mapped it(which implies you have a relation with name and index of some manner), so you have a constant time finding a solution, or some other solution for the constant time or you have iteration.

Comment: @tonitone120 without repeating i meant, i don't want an output array to have these two data  [{ name: "ben", age: 25 },{ name: "ben", age: 10 }]

Comment: @tonitone120 is right , thats what i meant

Comment: @tonitone120 but in your response i see  { name: "ben", age: 25 } and  {"name": "ben", "age": 10} in the same array

Answer (score -1):

Yours is a good case for `Array.prototype.findIndex` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)), which is like `Array.prototype.find` but returns the found index instead of the item.

```js
let a = [{ name: "ben", age: 25 }, { name: "jeffrey", age: 10 },{ name: "daniel", age: 20 }]
let case1 = { name: "ben", age: 10 }
let case2 = { name: "jack", age: 30 }

const arrayUpsert = function (array, object) {
  const objectIndex = array.findIndex(item => item.name == object.name)
  if (objectIndex == -1) {
    array.push(object)
  } else {
    array[objectIndex] = { ...array[objectIndex], ...object }
  }
  return array
}

console.log(arrayUpsert(a, case1))
console.log(arrayUpsert(a, case2))
/* [
  { name: 'ben', age: 10 },
  { name: 'jeffrey', age: 10 },
  { name: 'daniel', age: 20 }
]
[
  { name: 'ben', age: 10 },
  { name: 'jeffrey', age: 10 },
  { name: 'daniel', age: 20 },
  { name: 'jack', age: 30 }
] */
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be done with a `for` loop as well.

```js
function untitled(original, newObj) {
    for (let index = 0; index < original.length; index++) {
        if (original.name && newObj.name === a[index].name) {
            original[index] = {...newObj};
            console.log(original); return;
        }
    }
    original.push(newObj); console.log(original);
}

let a = [{ name: "ben", age: 25 }, { name: "jeffrey", age: 10 },{ name: "daniel", age: 20 }]
let case1 = { name: "ben", age: 10 }
let case2 = { name: "jack", age: 30 }

untitled(a, case1);
untitled(a, case2);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm using ramda library in my solution:-

- Check whether the key exist in any of the object in array by
  `idx = R.findIndex(R.propEq('name', 'ben'), a)`. If `idx<0` then we can directly push the object else go to the next step.
- We have the index(idx), we just have to do `a[idx].age="--"`.